# Mock call to .Net Core class library with DI

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I'm having trouble creating a console program to call the enrol method in referenced class library.  I cannot get the dependencies injected except the config.

The Class library contains the code to call:

```
public interface IMyClient
{
    Task DoSomething(Request request);
}

public class MyClient : IMyClient
{
    private readonly MyClientConfig _config;
    private readonly ILogger<MClient> _logger;
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public MyClient()
    {

    }

    public MyClient(MyClientConfig config, ILogger<MyClient> logger, HttpClient client)
    {
        _config = config;
        _logger = logger;
        _client = client;
    }

    public async Task DoSomething(Request request)
    {
        // BREAKPOINT HERE HAS config (id = 1) but logger & client are null
    }
}
```

And the console program

```
class Program
{
    private static IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RegisterServices();
        IServiceScope scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();

        var request = new Request()
        {
            Id = 1
        };

        scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMyClient>().DoSomething(request);

        DisposeServices();
    }

    private static void RegisterServices()
    {
        var myClientConfig = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
            .Build().GetSection("MyClient").Get<MyClientConfig>();


        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddSingleton<IMyClient, MyClient>();
        services.AddSingleton<IMyClientConfig>(myClientConfig);
        _serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider(true);
    }

    private static void DisposeServices()
    {
        if (_serviceProvider == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (_serviceProvider is IDisposable)
        {
            ((IDisposable)_serviceProvider).Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried adding in

`services.AddSingleton<HttpClient>(new HttpClient());`

to get the HttpCLient injected but to no avail.

Any help appreciated or advice on testing the call to DoSomething in the referenced project

Comment: Does the non-default constructor in `MyClient` get hit?

Comment: No it doesn't.  If I remove the empty constructor though the method doesn't get hit

Comment: What DI container framework are you using?

Comment: microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection Is that what you mean?

Comment: @downvoter, out of curiosity, why was this questions downvoted? I really can't see what this poster did so wrong in asking this question... would you please explain, just so that this user (and me, frankly) can learn? Thank you!

Comment: @CoolBots The title is misleading when compared to the explained problem. This also appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The question in its current state is also incomplete and therefore unclear. It does not show any research effort and is also not useful.

Comment: @CoolBots thanks, I'll take a look at the recommendations in your answer.

Comment: @user1919214 Glad to help. Checkout the [ask] page, when you have some time, for help clarifying any future questions you may have. Happy coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not configuring your `Logger` and `HttpClient` in `services`. You are also likely missing an additional Nuget package, `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console` - install that if it's missing, since you mentioned this is a Console App

Modify your code as follows:

```cs
    private static void RegisterServices()
    {

        var myClientConfig = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
                                .Build().GetSection("MyClient").Get<MyClientConfig>();

        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddSingleton<IMyClient, MyClient>();

        // Configure logging service
        services.AddLogging(cfg => cfg.AddConsole())
                .AddTransient<MyClient>();

        // Configure HttpClient - might need some constructor params, depending on your use case
        services.AddSingleton<HttpClient>(new HttpClient());

        _serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider(true);
    }
```

Also, *very important*: **remove your empty constructor** in `MyClient`! You *never* want that one hit! In fact, it's far better for the program to *crash* in debugging than hit that constructor, as it will create *appearance* of working - like the situation you're in now.

The reason your code "didn't do anything different" when you added the `services.AddSingleton<HttpClient>(new HttpClient());` code is *because of your empty constructor* - since the `Logger` service was still not configured, DI framework couldn't match the correct constructor - so instead of getting a meaningful error, the empty constructor ran (since it *always* matches) - causing *debugging pain and suffering*.

As an aside, I recommend reading up on how DI works underneath (maybe even build out your own DI container, a very simple one, for practice. *Do not* use your own DI container in production!). This is a good article, by the guy that practically invented this stuff: https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html